# Error: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, .d.ts

I am trying to export a function from a module file like and file name is logger.d.ts

```
import { Logger, LoggerSettings } from '../interfaces';
import { Audit } from './audit';
declare class MyLogger implements Logger {
    private winstonLogger;
    constructor(winstonLogger: any);
    error(logObj: any): void;
    warn(logObj: any): void;
    info(logObj: any): void;
    debug(logObj: any): void;
    verbose(logObj: any): void;
    silly(logObj: any): void;
}
export declare function createLogger(settings?: LoggerSettings): {
    audit: Audit;
    logger: MyLogger;
};
export {};
```

And i am trying to import it like

```
const { createLogger } = require('@website/website-node-logger');
const { audit } = createLogger;
```

and using this in same file like

```
audit.request({
  requestId: uuidv4(),
  email: user._id,
  type: constants.AUDIT_LOGS_TYPES.ARCHIVED_OLD_DATA,
  data: auditData,
  time: new Date().toLocaleString()
});
```

File paths are totally correct

Answer (score 0):

`createLogger` is a function. You should do `const { audit } = createLogger();`

Comment: winston.transports.DailyRotateFile is not a constructor

Comment: What does that mean? Your code above does not invoke `new` on `winston.transports.DailyRotateFile` , nor does it imply that it is not callable

Comment: @KanishkAnand How does this function get audit and logger? Don't you think there is a mistake in the function itself.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I agree. Both the code snippets seem to be in a disconnect